# Systemjs set package from root dir

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am working with Angular2. 
In the quickstart guide they have the following:

structure:

```
./
 app
   app.component.js
   main.js
 index.html
```

Config:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I am trying to modify the structure from the quickstart guide.

```
./
 app
   app.component.js
   main.js
   index.html
```

I have placed `index.html` inside `app/` and altered the import: `System.import('main')`

This does not work however. I believe it is because the file no longer lives in the `package` and so the `format` and `default` extension are not applied.

Is it possible to create a `package` for the root dir?